# add Jquery UI buttonset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having trouble adding dynamic radiobutton ,when using the jQuery UI's buttonset's.

Thanks

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myCars = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "21", "22", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11",];
        for (var i = 0; i < myCars.length; i++) {
            $("#main").append("<input type='radio' id='radio'" + i + " name='radio'>" + "<label for='radio" + i + "'>" + myCars[i] + "</label>");
        }
        $("#main").buttonset();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What kind of trouble?

Comment: `id='radio'" + i` will result in invalid markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit of code `id='radio'" + i + " name=...` is invalid.

It should be `id='radio" + i + "' name=...` (note the single quote after the double quote)

I've created a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9TDcN/1/)